# Identifying Cherry MX-5000 Keyboard controller chip ZC86963P

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, identification, keyboard

The Cherry MX 5000 ErgoPlus keyboard (model G80-5000 HAAUS) has been out of production since the 1990s. I'm trying to identify its controller chip. If I can locate a data sheet, I hope to dump the contents from an original unit, and if I can find a replacement chip, perhaps program it with different key assignments.

The 40-pin DIP IC has these markings:

(Motorola logo)
ZC86963P
635-1101
B51T
CTLAC9539

Photos:

[image: ZC86963P image 1]

[image: ZC86963P image 2]

My web searching hasn't turned up anything so far, so I'm hoping someone here will have some helpful pointers.

Comment: [This person](https://deskthority.net/viewtopic.php?t=21497) didn't have much luck

Comment: If you can't find the chip, you could consider replacing the entire controller (not just the chip) with a different one, they should be reasonably easy to find since the custom keyboard craze happened

Comment: A working device is expensive, 500 - 1400€. If you do not want to sell it, only use it, then you can use a STM32 with USB, define it as USB-HID device (keyboard) and scan the key-matrix. The circuit should be very easy to discover. Remove the chip, use the pins of a STM32 instead, replace the tantalum capacitor and the electrolytic with new ceramic types.